# How to plot 1D data in 2D?

Tags: python, arrays, plot

I have an array, which is consist of n^2 numbers. I need to make n*n 2D array out of it and then plot the data.

For example, plot of that 3*3 array:

```
[0, 1, 0, 
1, 2, 1, 
0, 2, 0]
```

should look like this:

[plot_example_010121020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THFKS.png)

How to plot it, using python? 
If I have to introduce x and y axes, how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `numpy` to reshape the array, then `matplotlib` to plot the result?

Comment: Use [`matshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.matshow.html) from matplotlib. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/matshow.html) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(1, 10)
s = int(np.sqrt(a.size))
b = a.reshape(s, s)

plt.matshow(b)
plt.show()
```

which gets you

```
>>> a
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

>>> b
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

and the graph looks like this

[image]

and using the input array you provided with cmaps="Reds":

[image]

Comment: I didnt do any kind of checking to guarantee that the input array is a perfect square in length. That's left as an exercise to the reader